# Add new edge to Graph and check if total weight is reduced

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I'm new to Graphs and I'm trying to solve this problem in Java:

Given a Graph with N nodes and N-1 weighted bidirectional edges, the algorithm must respond
YES if a new edge 'q' allows to reduce the overall weight of the graph, NO otherwise.

The edge 'q' satisfies this condition if there is an edge 'e' such that it is possible to
replace 'e' with 'q' leaving the graph connected and decreasing its overall weight.

I implemented the graph with adjacency list:

```
public class Vertex {
private final int element;
private final Set<Edge> edges; // Collection of edges to neighbors

public Vertex(int element) {
    this.element = element;
    edges = new HashSet<>();
}

public int getElement() {
    return element;
}

public boolean addEdge(Edge edge) {
    return edges.add(edge);
}

public List<Edge> getEdges() {
    return new ArrayList<>(edges);
}
}
```

Edge class:

```
public class Edge {
   private Vertex to;
private int weight;

public Edge(Vertex to, int weight) {
    super();
    this.to = to;
    this.weight = weight;
}

public Vertex getTo() {
    return to;
}
...
```

and a Graph class:

```
public class Graph {
   private final Set<Vertex> vertices; // Collection of all vertices

   public Graph() {
       vertices = new HashSet<>();
   }

   public List<Vertex> getVertices() {
       return new ArrayList<>(vertices);
   }

   public boolean addVertex(Vertex vertex) {
       return vertices.add(vertex);
   }
}
```

Is there an algorithm that I can use to solve the problem?

Comment: Is there only a single query for an edge `q`? Or multiple? If multiple then you only need to respond YES/NO without modifying the graph or replace that edge and use the modified graph for the rest of the queries?

Comment: There are multiple query, and for each query the graph must be the same graph, therefore after each query the graph must be restored

Comment: I need the same implementation for a project, did you find a valid algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Given a Graph with N nodes and N-1 weighted bidirectional edges,

Then the Graph is a [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)#Tree). (Assuming the Graph is connected.) A useful property of trees is that for any two nodes *s* and *t* in the tree, there exists a single unique (simple) path between them.

> the algorithm must respond YES if a new edge 'q' allows to reduce the overall weight of the graph, NO otherwise.

Adding a new edge between two nodes (say, *s* and *t*) in a tree creates a cycle. Removing any edge in this new cycle will create a new (connected) graph that is also a tree.

> The edge 'q' satisfies this condition if there is an edge 'e' such that it is possible to replace 'e' with 'q' leaving the graph connected and decreasing its overall weight.

This condition can only be satisfied if there exists one or more edges in the path from *s* to *t* (or *t* to *s*) whose weight is greater than the weight of the new edge *q*. If there are multiple such edges, any of them may be replaced.

Comment: So I need to simply add the new edge and check the cycle, once I find the cycle I have to find any edge with a weight lower than the one added and remove it.

Comment: The problem with the cycle is that I tried a method but it always return true because of this instructions: `map.get(edge.source).add(edge);
    map.get(edge.destination).add(edge);`. So every edge is a cycle. I don't know if is the implementation of the graph wrong or the cycle detect method

Comment: You need to remove an edge with a **higher** weight than the new edge if you want to reduce the total weight of the graph. Don't add the edge first. Just find the **path** between the endpoints of the new edge in the graph. Then you can remove any one of those edges, creating a disconnected graph. Adding in your new edge will re-connect the graph. I suggest doing one or two examples by hand.

Comment: I wrote the code that I added now up in the question, but I still miss something because it doesn't work properly

Comment: @Raul your code does not check edges in a path, but all edges adjacent to destination.

Comment: Yeah, I realized it now after having redesigned it on paper. I got stuck, now I'll write a method to find the path from source to destination and check if there is an edge with higher weight than the new edge, as @beaker said

Comment: Sorry, I had the name of the new edge wrong in the last paragraph. Fixed now.

Comment: I tried a dfs search path but it takes too much. For 18k new edges it takes 7 minutes. Wich algorithm should I use? My graphs are only with positive weights so I was thinking to Dijkstra.

Comment: In the largest dataset I have 100000 nodes to create the graph and 100000 new edges to add. I have to find something very fast because this it must run in less than 2 seconds.

Comment: Now I changed my implementation because I think it's impossible to solve this problem with this current implementation. I'll edit up in the answer